# Building Sharepoint 2010 workflows in SP 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint

I am trying to develop Workflows using Visual Studio 2012, which are in 2010 mode. I do not have the workflow manager installed, as not reqd for me. When I try to create the a VS project and add a workflow item, the solution shows an error: `Could not load file or assembly - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Sharepoint.WorkflowExtensions` and the Error List in the VS shows: `Please make sure workflow manager client and tools are installed properly`.

Can I use VS 2012 to build SP 2010 mode workflows? We cannot have the workflow manager installed at the moment, unfortunately.

I tried creating a blank Sharepoint 2010 project in the 2013 environment, but it asks for an instance of SharePoint 2010 to be provided.

Comment: to develop solutions for sp2010 you need to have sharepoint installed on the dev machine what is standard. I hope you wont do any developing on production

Comment: thanks...Actually SharePoint 2013 is installed on the DEV. I want to create workflows on this DEV, which are in 2010 mode. It seems the workflow manager is a prerequisite for any workflow to be built

Comment: yes it is, there is not other way to do this becouse even u you skip that kind of error u wont active feature with your workflow

Comment: Found out the issue...have to select the option "Create Sequential Workflow". This seems the old 2010 style one. The remaining steps worked fine